# How to achieve one to many relation ship data as coma separated in below format

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 2 tables and it is one to many relationship (parent & chdild). Its a dynamic table ,not a fixed data. More data can come in table.

```
user
Aid userName
1   author1
2   author2
3   author3
4   author4
etc

books
bid NAME Aid
1    x    1
2    y    1
3    z    2
4    z1   3
```

The Expected output is like below

```
'author1' AS author1,'x' AS x,'y' AS y,'author2' AS author2,'z' AS z,'author3' AS author3,'z1' AS z1
```

I have tried with parent table but how to get all row like in above format.

```
  select listagg('''' || UserName || ''' as "' || UserName || '"', ',') within group (order by Aid)
  from   (select distinct Aid,UserName  from user order by Aid);
```

Comment: Don't do this. If you want to pivot the data, do it in the third-party application (Java, C#, PHP, etc.) that you are using to access the database because that will support pivoting a data set rather than trying to force it through some dynamic SQL and trying to get a query to do something it is not intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't do this. If you want to pivot the data, do it in the third-party application (Java, C#, PHP, etc.) that you are using to access the database because that will support pivoting a data set rather than trying to force it through some dynamic SQL and trying to get a query to do something it is not intended to do.

---

However, if you really must (don't) then:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG('''' || name || ''' AS ' || name, ',')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) AS names
FROM   (
  SELECT username AS name
  FROM   "USER"
  UNION
  SELECT name
  FROM   books
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "USER" (Aid, userName) AS
SELECT 1, 'author1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'author2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'author3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'author4' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE books (bid, NAME, Aid) AS
SELECT 1, 'x',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'y',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'z',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'z1', 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NAMES |
| --- |
| 'author1' AS author1,'author2' AS author2,'author3' AS author3,'author4' AS author4,'x' AS x,'y' AS y,'z' AS z,'z1' AS z1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TCx3Pan7)

Comment: The o/p is not in the order as per expected result. I modified the query and I got the result but this is not perfect and fails in when data changes https://dbfiddle.uk/-_Gv_G_I

Comment: @bless If you are using this in a pivot in a dynamic SQL statement then the order is irrelevant.